# iStorage DatAshur PRO AES-XTS 256-bit - 15 Digit Pin Time Til Brute Force

Tags: aes

I am looking into the above encrypted usb drive, however, my concern is that its only a 15 digit pin of numeric characters, and I am not sure how to do the math on time til brute force...

Is a 15 digit pin of numeric characters really strong enough to prevent brute force?

Comment: 1 quadrillion combos at 1b/sec is about 6 days from the birthday paradox.